# Worklight - Can we deploy ear/war to worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Iam into a different usecase, 
Iam workling on General webapplications which we develop using rad for Websphere, and Worklight applications also.

My query here is, can we deploy my webapplication's ear/war file to the Worklight server?
We have a worklight server but dont have hosting for webaplication till now, so can we use the worklight server for hosting the webapplications' ear/war? is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: @user2065944, if your question is answered - please mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Worklight Server is able to process Worklight-based applications, not other type of "web-based" applications.

Comment: Thanks Idan for the reply, can we develope general webbased applications in the worklight?

Comment: Do you mean applications that can be accessed via the device's browser? If so then the answer is Yes. This is called Mobile Web apps. See this: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_12_-_Developing_Mobile_Web_apps.pdf

Comment: Yes you can develop general web based applications with Worklight.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original question is if we could use Worklight server to deploy EAR/WARs of any applications which are not related to Worklight.

Answer: When the Worklight is nothing but an J2EE application deployed in WAS or WAS Liberty Core, i dont see any issue deploying any EAR/WAR of applications which are not related to Worklight. But i dont think it is highly recommended or advisable since it is against the licensing policy in the Worklight purchase.